# How to count the number of instances where the wind directions is < (-3.54) for >= 5 consecutive days in a season

Tags: r

I have a data set of U wind direction recorded every day from 1993 to 2016. I would like to know how many instances there are in a season (let's say Autumn; from March to May) where U is <(-3.54) for >= 5 days. I have looked at previous questions and answers on stack overflow, but I haven't been able to find an example to guide me. Any help would be appreciated.

````````````````````````````````
A section of my data set looks like this:
```````````````````````````````
Year Month Day           U
1   1993     1   1   2.2752712
2   1993     1   2  -2.3828683
3   1993     1   3  -6.5054070
4   1993     1   4  -6.5550585
5   1993     1   5  -0.8896707
6   1993     1   6  -2.2694185
7   1993     1   7   1.6020930
8   1993     1   8   4.4161047
9   1993     1   9  -3.4612790
10  1993     1  10  -4.1855815
11  1993     1  11   4.3345735
12  1993     1  12   6.7505038
13  1993     1  13   2.7704460
14  1993     1  14  -0.3126935
15  1993     1  15  -5.2111823
16  1993     1  16   0.1577910
17  1993     1  17   3.2431200
18  1993     1  18   4.1351938
19  1993     1  19   8.8824225
20  1993     1  20  11.5171123
21  1993     1  21   8.4929847
22  1993     1  22  -0.6879845
23  1993     1  23   9.1634883
24  1993     1  24   8.0907365
25  1993     1  25  -5.9970930
26  1993     1  26 -11.9065697
27  1993     1  27  -0.0509885
28  1993     1  28  -0.9271122
29  1993     1  29  -1.2506782
30  1993     1  30   2.8655622
31  1993     1  31   5.1648452
32  1993     2   1  -0.6710272
33  1993     2   2  -0.1745542
34  1993     2   3   7.1772285
35  1993     2   4  -1.2568218
36  1993     2   5  -1.4439727
37  1993     2   6   0.6784107
38  1993     2   7   8.6756010
39  1993     2   8   1.5709885
40  1993     2   9  -6.4978875
41  1993     2  10   0.8981590
42  1993     2  11  -5.4501548
43  1993     2  12  -2.0549033
44  1993     2  13  -0.9364535
45  1993     2  14   2.3316280
46  1993     2  15   8.4644767
47  1993     2  16   4.2322285
48  1993     2  17  -4.2141278
49  1993     2  18  -7.1285853
50  1993     2  19  -3.9616670
51  1993     2  20   3.0711045
52  1993     2  21   0.8550193
53  1993     2  22   2.7637208
54  1993     2  23  -4.0326550
55  1993     2  24  -6.9834690
56  1993     2  25  -7.1804845
57  1993     2  26   2.7410468
58  1993     2  27   0.9994572
59  1993     2  28  -2.1881782
60  1993     3   1  -1.6012982
61  1993     3   2   0.4499225
62  1993     3   3  -2.4872480
63  1993     3   4  -2.1658527
64  1993     3   5  -1.4132365
65  1993     3   6   2.2400198
66  1993     3   7  -3.1068022
67  1993     3   8  -0.5415117
68  1993     3   9   0.9616280
69  1993     3  10  -7.1419960
70  1993     3  11   1.2279457
71  1993     3  12   6.1011240
72  1993     3  13   4.9892440
73  1993     3  14   4.8197285
74  1993     3  15   1.6525583
75  1993     3  16  -9.0284302
76  1993     3  17  -3.3607170
77  1993     3  18   5.7897092
78  1993     3  19  -2.5350580
79  1993     3  20  -3.1431975
80  1993     3  21   6.2275968
81  1993     3  22   0.9624417
82  1993     3  23  -8.9311823
83  1993     3  24  -9.6640115
84  1993     3  25  -9.7974420
85  1993     3  26  -3.8447093
86  1993     3  27   1.6185270
87  1993     3  28  -4.5626552
88  1993     3  29  -7.6756202
89  1993     3  30   5.4181783
90  1993     3  31   5.9135658
91  1993     4   1   3.4654847
92  1993     4   2  -2.1095738
93  1993     4   3  -9.3131203
94  1993     4   4  -8.1391280
95  1993     4   5 -10.7533140
96  1993     4   6   6.1808530
97  1993     4   7   5.7693025
98  1993     4   8   0.3322870
99  1993     4   9  10.3273835
100 1993     4  10   5.7872480
101 1993     4  11   0.8317830
102 1993     4  12  -0.7549225
103 1993     4  13  11.9887015
104 1993     4  14   4.1117440
105 1993     4  15   1.2044572
106 1993     4  16   1.3899808
107 1993     4  17  11.2100388
108 1993     4  18   8.2815310
109 1993     4  19  -0.8285080
110 1993     4  20  -5.7935273
111 1993     4  21  -4.0424420
112 1993     4  22  -0.5786045
113 1993     4  23   0.3742055
114 1993     4  24  -0.4698642
115 1993     4  25  -0.3981780
116 1993     4  26   5.5060660
117 1993     4  27   5.0961628
118 1993     4  28   4.3308137
119 1993     4  29   7.8211433
120 1993     4  30   1.4068415
121 1993     5   1  -6.0343218
122 1993     5   2   2.5626165
123 1993     5   3  -0.2517055
124 1993     5   4  -0.3624998
125 1993     5   5   5.4518413
126 1993     5   6   8.0799417
127 1993     5   7   9.6727713
128 1993     5   8   6.9166862
129 1993     5   9   5.1044767
130 1993     5  10  -3.5812015
131 1993     5  11  -0.6386435
132 1993     5  12   3.8953680
133 1993     5  13   2.2846125
134 1993     5  14   6.8920930
135 1993     5  15   6.3412790
136 1993     5  16   9.9857557
137 1993     5  17   4.9041085
138 1993     5  18   1.2711628
139 1993     5  19  -0.8744572
140 1993     5  20  -1.7563565
141 1993     5  21   7.7133918
142 1993     5  22   1.8609305
143 1993     5  23   5.0106588
144 1993     5  24   2.2513178
145 1993     5  25   9.8685660
146 1993     5  26  17.1051357
147 1993     5  27  15.9958140
148 1993     5  28  11.9747288
149 1993     5  29  10.4338953
150 1993     5  30   9.8273450
151 1993     5  31   2.9315697
152 1993     6   1  -4.8080815
153 1993     6   2   7.4390697
154 1993     6   3   9.7631200
155 1993     6   4   3.0179265
156 1993     6   5  -0.9081978
157 1993     6   6   0.8990115
158 1993     6   7  -1.6712595
159 1993     6   8  -6.6958335
160 1993     6   9   3.0657173
161 1993     6  10   2.8695543
162 1993     6  11  14.8854070
163 1993     6  12   6.0319572
164 1993     6  13  -0.8188955
165 1993     6  14  -2.1511820
166 1993     6  15   2.8237210
167 1993     6  16   6.0374808
168 1993     6  17   5.7747092
169 1993     6  18   3.7086240
170 1993     6  19  11.2165893
171 1993     6  20  13.0581202
172 1993     6  21  10.7091860
173 1993     6  22   5.5876357
174 1993     6  23   7.3413180
175 1993     6  24  -3.0820543
176 1993     6  25  -0.4195735
177 1993     6  26   2.3836045
178 1993     6  27  -3.6750388
179 1993     6  28  10.1507362
180 1993     6  29  11.7455232
181 1993     6  30   4.6698065
```````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, have corrected it.

Comment: In your data is no such sequence with `U < -3.54` for >= 5 days.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
with(rle(Data$U < -3.54), sum(values==TRUE & lengths>=5))
```

You want to explore only some months:

```
D <- subset(Data, Month %in% 3:5)
with(rle(D$U < -3.54), sum(values==TRUE & lengths>=5))
```

There is no such sequence.
To have some data in the result I changed the task a little bit:

```
R <- rle(D$U > -3.54)
Rdat <- with(R, data.frame(values, lengths))
Rdat$start <- 1 + cumsum(c(0, head(Rdat$lengths, -1)))
Ri <- subset(Rdat, values==TRUE & lengths>=5)
cbind(D[Ri$start,], Ri$lengths)
```

The result are the starting days of the sequences.

```
#> cbind(D[Ri$start,], Ri$lengths)
#    Year Month Day          U Ri$lengths
#60  1993     3   1 -1.6012982          9
#70  1993     3  11  1.2279457          5
#76  1993     3  17 -3.3607170          6
#96  1993     4   6  6.1808530         14
#112 1993     4  22 -0.5786045          9
#122 1993     5   2  2.5626165          8
#131 1993     5  11 -0.6386435         21
```

Comment: Thank you for this, the only problem is that the code doesn't specify the season. However, I have managed to figure it out using the code from @Aron below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way with `dplyr` that also keeps the first day of each instance.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(Month %in% 3:5) %>%
  mutate(threshold = U > -3.54,
         group = cumsum(threshold != lag(threshold, default = FALSE))) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(n_days = n()) %>%
  summarise_all(first) %>%
  filter(threshold, n_days >= 5) %>%
  select(-group, -threshold) -> instances

instances
# A tibble: 7 x 5
   Year Month   Day      U n_days
  <int> <int> <int>  <dbl>  <int>
1  1993     3     1 -1.60       9
2  1993     3    11  1.23       5
3  1993     3    17 -3.36       6
4  1993     4     6  6.18      14
5  1993     4    22 -0.579      9
6  1993     5     2  2.56       8
7  1993     5    11 -0.639     21

nrow(instances)
[1] 7
```